# django-auth-ldap installation not working

Tags: python, django, authentication, ldap

I am trying to install django-auth-ldap in my windows system it shows the following error

> \pip-build-3x6rkxb4\pyldap\modules\errors.h(8): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'lber.h': No such file or directory
>   error: command 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\BIN\x86_amd64\cl.exe' failed with exit status 2

```
# LDAP auth settings.
LDAP_AUTH_URL = os.environ.get("LDAP_AUTH_URL", "ldap://xxx.xx.xx.xx:389")
LDAP_AUTH_USE_TLS = False

LDAP_AUTH_SEARCH_BASE = "dc=maxcrc,dc=com" 
LDAP_AUTH_OBJECT_CLASS = "inetOrgPerson"
LDAP_AUTH_USER_FIELDS = {
    "username": "uid",
    "first_name": "givenName",
    "last_name": "sn",
    "email": "mail",
}
LDAP_AUTH_USER_LOOKUP_FIELDS = ("username",)
LDAP_AUTH_CLEAN_USER_DATA = "django_python3_ldap.utils.clean_user_data"
LDAP_AUTH_SYNC_USER_RELATIONS = "django_python3_ldap.utils.sync_user_relations"
LDAP_AUTH_FORMAT_SEARCH_FILTERS = "django_python3_ldap.utils.format_search_filters"
LDAP_AUTH_FORMAT_USERNAME = "django_python3_ldap.utils.format_username_openldap"
LDAP_AUTH_ACTIVE_DIRECTORY_DOMAIN = None 
LDAP_AUTH_CONNECTION_USERNAME = "cn=Manager,dc=maxcrc,dc=com" 
LDAP_AUTH_CONNECTION_PASSWORD = "*****" 

LDAP_AUTH_CONNECT_TIMEOUT = None
LDAP_AUTH_RECEIVE_TIMEOUT = None

AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = (
    "django_python3_ldap.auth.LDAPBackend",
)
```

My versions are
Python - 3.6.3 (64bit)
Django - 1.11.6 (64bit)
Windows 10 - 64bit

Thanks

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`django-auth-ldap` needs to be compiled due to its dependencies. Especially on Windows, I'd recommend trying a pure Python solution. The one I use which works very well, is `django-python3-ldap`, which you can find here:

https://github.com/etianen/django-python3-ldap

Here is how I set up the settings, so that we can connect using these values with `ldap3` directly as well:

```
AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = [
    'django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend',
    'django_python3_ldap.auth.LDAPBackend',
]

# LDAP Connection Settings
LDAP_AUTH_HOST = 'ldap.example.com'
LDAP_AUTH_PORT = 636
LDAP_AUTH_URL = 'ldaps://{host}:{port}'.format(
    host=LDAP_AUTH_HOST,
    port=LDAP_AUTH_PORT,
)
LDAP_AUTH_CONNECTION_USERNAME = 'ldapuser'
LDAP_AUTH_CONNECTION_PASSWORD = 'ldappassword'

# Initiate TLS on connection.
LDAP_AUTH_USE_TLS = True

# The LDAP search base for looking up users.
LDAP_AUTH_SEARCH_BASE = "ou=People,dc=example,dc=com"

# The LDAP class that represents a user.
LDAP_AUTH_OBJECT_CLASS = "shadowAccount"

# User model fields mapped to the LDAP
# attributes that represent them.
LDAP_AUTH_USER_FIELDS = {
    "username": "uid",
}

# A tuple of fields used to uniquely identify a user.
LDAP_AUTH_USER_LOOKUP_FIELDS = ("username",)
```

The README also includes instructions for Active Directory, if that's what you're connecting to. Good luck!

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Right now I am working in "django-python3-ldap". I have configured the setting.py as follow as their document and I can run the "python manage.py ldap_sync_users" command to synchronized the data to my database. But If I am trying to authenticate via my view.py it returned the "LDAP connect failed: LDAPInvalidCredentialsResult - 49 - invalidCredentials - None - None - bindResponse - None" error.

Comment: Are you trying to connect to Active Directory or OpenLDAP? Do you know what LDAP schema you're using? It sounds like it is connecting, but your configuration settings need to be tweaked to authenticate properly.

Comment: I am using OpenLDAP but not sure about the schema been used. I have updated configuration settings detail in my question section.

Comment: We used `shadowAccount`. I've amended my answer to include an example configuration for this setup. You can connect to your OpenLDAP server and browse your schema with something like LDAPAdmin: http://www.ldapadmin.org/

Comment: I have fixed this issue. Thanks FlipperPA

Comment: Congrats! What was it? I'm glad the package it working out for you, it has been reliable for us over many versions of Django.

Comment: How to connect AWS Microsoft AD using that for Django application?

Answer (score 6):

For those who, like me, cannot leave django-auth-ldap for whatever reason: I solved downloading and installing the binary wheel of python-ldap from here

https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#python-ldap

I hope this helps