# Django with Ldap installation build failed

Tags: python, django, ldap

I'm new to Python Django and I'm building my Django application on Windows 7. My requirement is to integrate LDAP with Django. So I followed the below URL to install LDAP

[Installation- Django-LDAP](http://django-auth-ldap.readthedocs.io/en/latest/install.html)

When I try to install LDAP followed by

```
pip install django-auth-ldap
```

Then I'm getting

```
Collecting django-auth-ldap
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/c1/c4/e1586a835b5bf76d4d914f1622020ae9ab9d9be7149e216e19c8428670d1/d
jango_auth_ldap-1.7.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Requirement already satisfied: Django>=1.11 in c:\users\ccduce\appdata\local\continuum\miniconda3\lib\site-packages (from d
jango-auth-ldap) (2.0.6)
Collecting python-ldap>=3.1 (from django-auth-ldap)
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/7f/1c/28d721dff2fcd2fef9d55b40df63a00be26ec8a11e8c6fc612ae642f9cfd/p

ython-ldap-3.1.0.tar.gz
Requirement already satisfied: pytz in c:\users\ccduce\appdata\local\continuum\miniconda3\lib\site-packages (from Django>=1
.11->django-auth-ldap) (2018.4)
Requirement already satisfied: pyasn1>=0.3.7 in c:\users\ccduce\appdata\local\continuum\miniconda3\lib\site-packages (from
python-ldap>=3.1->django-auth-ldap) (0.4.4)
Requirement already satisfied: pyasn1_modules>=0.1.5 in c:\users\ccduce\appdata\local\continuum\miniconda3\lib\site-package
s (from python-ldap>=3.1->django-auth-ldap) (0.2.2)
Building wheels for collected packages: python-ldap
  Running setup.py bdist_wheel for python-ldap ... error
  Complete output from command c:\users\ccduce\appdata\local\continuum\miniconda3\python.exe -u -c "import setuptools, toke
nize;__file__='C:\\Users\\ccduce\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-c5a5rvyv\\python-ldap\\setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'o
pen', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" bdist_wheel -d C
:\Users\ccduce\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-wheel-6ztc_mq2 --python-tag cp36:
polls\views.py17:1
LFUTF-8Python0 files
running build_ext
  building '_ldap' extension
  error: [WinError 3] The system cannot find the path specified: 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\\VC
\\PlatformSDK\\lib'


  ----------------------------------------
  Failed building wheel for python-ldap
  Running setup.py clean for python-ldap
Failed to build python-ldap
Installing collected packages: python-ldap, django-auth-ldap
  Running setup.py install for python-ldap ... error
    Complete output from command c:\users\ccduce\appdata\local\continuum\miniconda3\python.exe -u -c "import setuptools, to
kenize;__file__='C:\\Users\\ccduce\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-c5a5rvyv\\python-ldap\\setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize,
'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --reco
rd C:\Users\ccduce\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-7f0q21s7\install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile:

    running install
    running build
polls\views.py17:1
LFUTF-8Python0 files
creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.6
    copying Lib\ldapurl.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6
    copying Lib\ldif.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\ldap
    copying Lib\ldap\async.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\ldap
    copying Lib\ldap\asyncsearch.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\ldap
    copying Lib\ldap\cidict.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\ldap
    copying Lib\ldap\compat.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\ldap
    copying Lib\ldap\constants.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\ldap
    copying Lib\ldap\dn.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\ldap
    copying Lib\ldap\filter.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\ldap
    copying Lib\ldap\functions.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\ldap

    copying Lib\ldap\ldapobject.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\ldap
    copying Lib\ldap\logger.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\ldap
    copying Lib\ldap\modlist.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\ldap
    copying Lib\ldap\pkginfo.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\ldap
    copying Lib\ldap\resiter.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\ldap
    copying Lib\ldap\sasl.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\ldap
    copying Lib\ldap\syncrepl.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\ldap
    copying Lib\ldap\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\ldap
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\ldap\controls
    copying Lib\ldap\controls\deref.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\ldap\controls
    copying Lib\ldap\controls\libldap.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\ldap\controls
    copying Lib\ldap\controls\openldap.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\ldap\controls
    copying Lib\ldap\controls\pagedresults.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\ldap\controls
polls\views.py17:1
LFUTF-8Python0 files
running build_ext
    building '_ldap' extension
    error: [WinError 3] The system cannot find the path specified: 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\\
VC\\PlatformSDK\\lib'

    ----------------------------------------
Command "c:\users\ccduce\appdata\local\continuum\miniconda3\python.exe -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='C:\\Use
rs\\ccduce\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-c5a5rvyv\\python-ldap\\setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);
code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record C:\Users\ccduce\AppDa
ta\Local\Temp\pip-record-7f0q21s7\install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code
1 in C:\Users\ccduce\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-c5a5rvyv\python-ldap\
```

I would be thankful if someone helps me to escape from this issue, bcz I'm struggling more than a couple of days to resolve this issue and also I am not clear why it is looking into Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0(The system cannot find the path specified:

```
'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\\
VC\\PlatformSDK\\lib')
```

Comment: This error comes up when you don't have Windows SDK installed.

Comment: @JonhyBeebop thank you. I need to integrate LDAP using Django so could you please suggest the best guide for that.

Comment: [https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=8279](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=8279)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue a while ago, used wheel file. You may use a proper wheel file (which has all the depencies in it) for your Python version [django-auth-ldap-installation-not-working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47048542/django-auth-ldap-installation-not-working)